# Domain and Range of function, perimeter, if maximum side length is $10$m

Tags: functions

I was wondering how I had to solve this question?

The maximum side length of the rectangle is $10$m. L: $(x+4)$, W: $(x-1)$

a) Write a function which gives perimeter, $P$ metres, of the rectangle.

b) State the domain and range of this function.

I tried approaching it from $10-x-4$, which would give me $6-x$ for length. Then $10-x+1$, which would give me $11-x$ for width. But, that wouldn't make sense since the width is suddenly bigger.

So I tried $10-x+4$, which would give me $14-x$ and $10-x-1$, which would give me $9-x$. This would mean that the perimeter is $46-4x$, and my domain will be $[1.5,9]$. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I put in my effort after editing. I forgot to put it in when I initially posted this.

Answer (score 1):

a) $$P=2L+2W = 2(x+4)+2(x-1) = 4x+6$$

b) Domain is $$1<x\le 6$$

Range is  $$ 10<P\le 30$$

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani: Don't you mean: $1 < x \le 6$ (and hence $10 < P \le 30)$?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my solution.